# How can a method exist in one part of the program but not another?

Tags: java, debugging, nio, bytebuffer, nosuchmethoderror

### Main question/TLDR: I am getting a NoSuchMethodError for a method a few levels down in my call stack. But calling the method in my own main function in the same project gives no error. How can that happen? What techniques could I try to narrow down the source of such an error?

Other facts: The documentation shows that the method exists. The source from which the error is raised has the right imports and tries to call the method. There is some weird gobbledygook after the name of the method in the error printout. Could this be the problem?

Specific information for my case:

Full error printout:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
at it.unimi.dsi.sux4j.io.ChunkedHashStore.reset(ChunkedHashStore.java:526)
at it.unimi.dsi.sux4j.mph.GOVMinimalPerfectHashFunction.<init>(GOVMinimalPerfectHashFunction.java:335)
at it.unimi.dsi.sux4j.mph.GOVMinimalPerfectHashFunction$Builder.build(GOVMinimalPerfectHashFunction.java:270)
at org.boydwebb.familysearch.runners.examples.ManyGraphWriter.<init>(ManyGraphWriter.java:109)
at org.boydwebb.familysearch.runners.examples.ManyGraphWriter.main(ManyGraphWriter.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
at org.boydwebb.familysearch.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:62)
at org.boydwebb.familysearch.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:23)
```

Relevant source:  (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vigna/Sux4J/master/src/it/unimi/dsi/sux4j/io/ChunkedHashStore.java)

Lines I inserted into main to try to get a minimal working example:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(100);
buffer.clear();
```

The lines in my original code the yielded the error:

```
import it.unimi.dsi.sux4j.mph.GOVMinimalPerfectHashFunction;
Long[] table = \*initialize here*\
TransformationStrategy<Long> transformationStrategy = TransformationStrategies.fixedLong();
GOVMinimalPerfectHashFunction.Builder<Long> builder = new GOVMinimalPerfectHashFunction.Builder<>();
builder.keys(Arrays.asList(table));
builder.transform(transformationStrategy);
builder.store(null);
builder.tempDir(null);
builder.signed(0);
toGiantIdx = builder.build();//ERROR HERE
```

Comment: The requested method (`ByteBuffer ByteBuffer.clear();`)exists since Java SE 9. If the code is executed with an older Java runtime, this error will happen. If your own code is compiled with an older JDK, the `buffer.clear()` will point to `Buffer Buffer.clear();` method (which exists since JDK 1.4).

Comment: This may be exactly the problem since I am compiling and running with Java 8. So the idea is that when I compile my own code, it finds Buffer.clear() and thus gives no error, but the library code comes pre-compiled, so it is already expecting ByteBuffer.clear(), and the check is not redone when I compile?

Comment: Exactly. The precompiled bytecode contains a reference to a method named internally as `java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;` which means the method full name is `java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear`, taking no parameters and returning an object of type `java.nio.ByteBuffer`. These things are not checked at compile time for a precompiled library.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I had some issues changing over to Java 9, but I was finally able to confirm that you were right! If you want to move your comments to an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precompiled library bytecode contains a reference to a method named internally as `java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;` which means a method defined in `java.nio.ByteBuffer` (maybe overridden in derived class) with declaration

```
java.nio.ByteBuffer clear();
```

This requested method exists since Java SE 9. If the code is executed with an older Java runtime, this error will happen.

If your own code is compiled with an older JDK, the compiler resolves the `buffer.clear()` to point to `java.nio.Buffer java.nio.Buffer.clear()` method instead (which exists since JDK 1.4).